# Trigg Oozie workflow from input-event even if missing

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I have classic coordinator with input-event on HDFS path.

```
<datasets>
    <dataset name="rawData" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" initial-instance="${startDate}" timezone="UTC">
        <uri-template>
            ${rawData}/${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}
        </uri-template>
        <done-flag>_SUCCESS</done-flag>
    </dataset>
</datasets>



<input-events>
    <data-in name="inputRawData" dataset="rawData">
        <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
    </data-in>
</input-events>
```

It's working well.
Now I'm looking to force workflow to run EVEN if input-events is not OK after X times.

PseudoCode :

```
Wait inputEvent

If(inputEvent):
    run.

else if(waitTme > 10min):
    run.
```

My application will read the lastAvailable data in specific HiveTables.

Thanks.